# Trying to Multiply a Case Statement to a Count

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetimeoffset, 
        @EndDate datetimeoffset

SET @StartDate = '2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 +07:00'
SET @EndDate = '2022-03-06 23:59:59.000 +07:00'

SELECT 
    Records.RecordID, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Records.RecDate AT TIME ZONE 'SE Asia Standard Time',104) AS RecTime,
    LocationStr, LocationName, 
    CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) AS Username ,ProductCodeName,
    CASE 
        WHEN AssetTypeName LIKE '%LTR' 
            THEN LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 3) 
            ELSE LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 2) 
    END * COUNT (ProductCodeName) AS 'SumProduct'
FROM 
    opendata.records
INNER JOIN 
    opendata.RecAssets ON Records.RecordId = RecAssets.RecordId
WHERE 
    (Records.ActionName = 'Fill') 
    AND (IsDeleted = '0') 
    AND (Records.RecDate BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate) 
    AND (LocationStr = '3031')
GROUP BY 
    Records.RecordId, Records.RecDate, LocationStr, LocationName, 
    CONCAT(FirstName,' ', LastName), ProductCodeName, AssetTypeName
ORDER BY 
    LocationStr ASC, RecTime ASC, ProductCodeName ASC
```

Tried to multiply the last to column on my Select statement but failed to do so. I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.

Furthermore, I tried to convert the case statement to an int but also failed. How can I directly multiply it?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Some of your rows have such data in AssetTypeName that your extraction  LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 2)  (or -3) does not result in pure digits; therefore it can't be converted to a number, and the query fails. You can try listing distinct values of those to see what causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using sql server seeing as it's not oracle and `len()` is not supported in mySQL or Postgres. You're code calls for an implicit conversion from a numerical value in a char type to a number, for example `'123'` to  `123`.
In the following example this doesn't present a problem the first time, but the second time there is a letter in the char value which cannot be converted and throws an error.
I am therefore thinking that you have values of `AssetTypeName` where there are letters other than in the last 2 characters for non-LTR values of elsewhere in the string for those ending in LTR.

> ```
> create table test(
> AssetTypeName varchar(10),
> ProductCodeName int);
> insert into test values
> ('123LTR',1),
> ('123LTR',1),
> ('123AB',1);
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select
> AssetTypeName,
> CASE 
>  WHEN AssetTypeName LIKE '%LTR' 
>             THEN LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 3) 
>             ELSE LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 2) 
> END * COUNT (ProductCodeName) AS 'SumProduct'
> from test
> group by AssetTypeName;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> AssetTypeName | SumProduct
> :------------ | ---------:
> 123AB         |        123
> 123LTR        |        246
> ```

> ```
> insert into test values ('123ABC',1);
> GO
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select
> AssetTypeName,
> CASE 
>  WHEN AssetTypeName LIKE '%LTR' 
>             THEN LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 3) 
>             ELSE LEFT(AssetTypeName, LEN(AssetTypeName) - 2) 
> END * COUNT (ProductCodeName) AS 'SumProduct'
> from test
> group by AssetTypeName;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 245 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
> ```

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '123A' to data type int.

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=f426a4891b2a237e04d6b54eae6c4b31)*